# Get the Top 10 entries in an Array

Tags: crystal-reports

Every ID in my array is printing out, but I only want to see the top 10.

```
WhileReadingRecords;
Local StringVar Key := "" & {Kunde.Kunden-ID};

StringVar array Keys;
if not(Key in Keys) then
( redim preserve Keys [count(Keys)+1];

Keys[count(Keys)]:= Key);
```

I use this formula, plus another formula for printing out the array content. Something like `Join ("",Keys) whilePrintingRecords`.

How can I achieve the desired behavior? I tried to put my values from a specific field in an array but failed to make it work.

Comment: Honestly..I couldn't understand your formula... can you explain what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was data in main the Details section, you might get by with just adding `RecordNumber > 10` to the *Suppress (No Drill-Down)* formula. It's a little more complicated with arrays, but doable:

For starters, make a new formula called *Declaration* and put it in the group header:

```
Shared NumberVar topCount := 0;
```

Then put this logic into the formula that determines whether or not to suppress detail entries:

```
Shared NumberVar topCount := topCount + 1;
topCount > 10;
```

Done correctly, this will show the top ten entries, but suppress any that follow.